# Not able to connect to MSI error while executing the script on this line az login --serviceprincipal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

```
az login --service-principal --username $AppId --tenant $tenantId --cert path to cert;
```

I have added the above line in the script. I'm getting this error while executing the script on this line.
Actually I want to implement non-human login in my script. I want to login via app in my script. How can I fix this error?

> Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly and check the network connection.

```
Error detail: HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80):  
Max retries exceeded with url: /metadata/identity/oauth2/token?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F&api-version=2018-02-01&client_id = $clientId
(Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x04035928>,
'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out.
(connect timeout=None)'))
```

Actually I want to implement non-human login in my script. I want to login via app in my script. How can I fix this error or if there is any other way to login in app?

Answer (score 0):

**To connect to `az` using Service principal certificate based login, check the below:**

Initially login with the user who have the permissions to create the Service Principal:

Create the Service Principal and enable certificate:

```bash
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac --name 'testaz' --create-cert
```

[image]

Now copy the path to the certificate which is generated after creating Service Principal **`fileWithCertAndPrivateKey`** and pass the values and connect to az:

```bash
az login --service-principal --username 'AppID' --tenant 'TenantID' --password 'C:\\Users\rukmini\\tmpgk32vq91.pem'
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create a service principal containing a certificate using Azure CLI | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-sp-tutorial-3#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-using-a-certificate)